# Get first and last date of week from a specific DATE

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a date in T-SQL. So I want to get the first date and the last date of week.

For example I have this date : 2017-09-19. I want to have 2017-09-18 and 2017-09-24

How can I get this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```
SELECT 
   DATEADD(dd, -(DATEPART(dw, yourDateInput)-1), yourDateInput) AS Weekstart
  ,DATEADD(dd, 7-(DATEPART(dw, yourDateInput)), yourDateInput) As weekEnd;
```

Note that: the first day of the week depends on the language settings on your sql server.

So if you got 17 - 23 start and end dates, then Sunday is the first day of the week.

So in this case, you might need to use:

```
SET DATEFIRST 1;
```

To set Monday to be the first day of the week.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to run the following query, it will give you everything you want :)

```
DECLARE @b DATE = '20170918'   --put your date here

DECLARE @a DATE


Print('First day of Current Week:')
set @a = dateadd(ww, Datediff(ww,0,@b),0)
Print(@a)
Print('')

Print('Last day of Current Week:')
set @a = dateadd(ww, Datediff(ww,0,@b)+1,-1)
Print(@a)
Print('')

--additional queries
SET @a =dateadd(mm, Datediff(mm,0,@b),0)
Print('First day of Current Month:')
Print(@a)
Print('')

set @a = dateadd(mm, Datediff(mm,0,@b)+1,-1)
Print('Last day of Current Month:')
Print(@a)
Print('')

Print('First day of Last Month:')
set @a = dateadd(mm, Datediff(mm,0,@b)-1,0)
Print(@a)
Print('')

Print('Last day of Last Month:') 
set @a = dateadd(mm, Datediff(mm,0,@b),-1)
Print(@a)
Print('')


Print('First day of Last Week:')
set @a =  dateadd(ww, Datediff(ww,0,@b)-1,0)
Print(@a)
Print('')

Print('Last day of Last Week:')
set @a =  dateadd(ww, Datediff(ww,0,@b),-1)
Print(@a)
```